# Issues with Shutting a Singleton pattern On and Off

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton

I'm currently testing the singleton pattern with a simple game of breakout. the way I'm implementing the singleton pattern is this.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Check if about to be destroyed
    private static bool bShutOff = false;
    private static object oLock = new object();
    private static T oInstance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // First check if this object is OFF 
            if (bShutOff)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Singleton instance '" + typeof(T) + "' already destroyed. Returning null.");
                return null;
            }

            lock (oLock)
            {
                if (oInstance == null)
                {
                    //Search for exissting instance 
                    oInstance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                    // If it still doesn't find one, it creates a new one 
                    if (oInstance == null)
                    {
                        // Creates a game object to attach the singleton 
                        var oSingletonObject = new GameObject();
                        oInstance = oSingletonObject.AddComponent<T>();
                        oSingletonObject.name = typeof(T).ToString() + "(Singleton)";

                        // Make the instance persisten in the world 
                        DontDestroyOnLoad(oSingletonObject);
                    }

                }

                return oInstance;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        bShutOff = true;
    }


    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        bShutOff = true;
    }

}
```

And the pattern is being used by a class named GameSession (deleted some code for visibility)

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GameSession : Singleton<GameSession>
{
    // Avoids non-singleton construuctor use
    protected GameSession() { }

    // config params 
    [Range(0.1f, 2f)] [SerializeField] float fGameSpeed = 1f; // Range le añade un rango maximo un valor serializado
    [SerializeField] int nPointsPerBlock = 50;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI tScore;

    // State variables
    [SerializeField] int nCurScore = 0;


    void Start()
    {
        tScore.text = nCurScore.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Time.timeScale = fGameSpeed; // normal time
    }

    public void AddScore()
    {
        nCurScore += nPointsPerBlock;
        tScore.text = nCurScore.ToString();
    }

}
```

At first it works no issue, but as soon as the object get's destroyed (by going to a diffrent scene) the boolean bShutOff is set to True (expected) but then since bShutOff is True, None of the other functions of the code work and I get my debug message "Debug.LogWarning("Singleton instance '" + typeof(T) + "' already destroyed. Returning null.");" (also expected if the object is supposed to be Off) I guess it's because of the  DontDestroyOnLoad(oSingletonObject);  logic not being in there at first(?) I'm fairly new to unity and the singleton pattern, so if anyone could point me in the right direction that  would be nice.

Comment: What do you need the `bShutOff` for at all? Wouldn't you explicitly want an instance to be created in case it doesn't exist? Or in other words in which case would you want to set it to `false` again?

Comment: I'm following this as reference http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton And you make a very good point, I thought it was weird as well, should I just remove all that from my code then?

Comment: It totally depends on how you want to use that "Singleton" ... what is your actual usecase?

Comment: I'm using it to keep the score of the player trough the levels in a breakout game, the issue starts when changing from scene to scene and also when I restart the game.

Comment: This sounds to me like the Singleton isn't really working and you are getting multiple concurrent instances is this possible? You should maybe add something like `private void Awake() { if(oInstance && oInstance != this) { Destroy(gameObject); } else { oInstance = this; bShutOff = false; }` or something like that. But yeah due to `DontDestroyOnLoad` it shouldn't be destroyed on scene changes...

Comment: That's the same I was thinking, it should't and it is causing the issue of multiple gameSessions. I'll try your code! this should be on the code of the class that inherits from the singleton right? not in the singleton itself?

Comment: it should be in the base class. It makes sure you really have a "Singleton" which has its name because there should exist only exactly one **single** instance .. the original code you have doesn't assure that at all...